# "localhost" not default /var/www/html/index/index.html

Tags: apache2

I have just installed apache2. My default file for "localhost" does not seem to be the file that is located in /var/www/html/index/.

To get to that file I have to type in 127.0.0.1: or 127.101.0.1:80 in mozilla.

Keep in mind that I'm very new to this so try keeping the terms fairly simple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The default DocumentRoot for Apache is `/var/www/html/` (without the `index/`) since Ubuntu 14.04 and `/var/www/` in older Ubuntu versions.

Comment: I was planning on typing index.html but I guess it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your /etc/hosts file has the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Your issue seems to be your system not going to `127.0.0.1` when you put in `localhost`, as it gives you the expected results when you use `127.0.0.1` but not `localhost`, as they should give you the same results, since `localhost` should point to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: How do I get to that file and change it?

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Comment: or `sudo mousepad /etc/hosts`

Comment: or `sudo gedit /etc/hosts`

Comment: What should I call the file? It's just a directory.

Comment: On my system it is a file.  Could you tell me what is in the directory?

Comment: Yeah It's a file now, I was mistaken.
But when I write 'localhost' in my browser the same thing pops up.